# Creating a new XWPFDocument after updating libraries does not work

Tags: java, javafx, libraries, compatibility

I trying to update the libraries in a JavaFX project. Unfortunately after updating them, one functionality - creating a DOC file - doesn't work anymore.

The code goes into this line of code :

```
resultDocument = new XWPFDocument();
```

and doesn't come out. There is no exception and it doesn't freeze.

I think there is a compatibility issue with the libraries. This are the libraries that I am using:

- commons-codec-1.16.0
- commons-compress-1.23.0
- commons-io-2.13.0
- commons-lang3-3.13.0
- commons-logging-1.2
- controlsfx-8.40.16
- dom4j-2.1.4
- gembox-spreadsheet
- geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0
- guava-32.1.2-jre
- jsoup-1.16.1
- jsr305-3.0.2
- log4j-1.2-api-2.20.0
- log4j-api-2.20.0
- log4j-core-2.20.0
- poi-5.2.3
- poi-ooxml-5.2.3
- poi-ooxml-full-5.2.3
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2
- saxon-9.1.0.8
- saxon-dom-9.1.0.8
- stax-api-1.0.1
- xbean
- xbean_xpath
- xml-apis-1.4.1
- xmlbeans-5.1.1
- zip4j-2.11.5

I am using jre1.8.0_361 fr this project.
Do you have any ideas?